Jenkins and/or Docker sometimes break with: npm WARN cleanup Failed to remove some directories
our team often has random problems with NPM builds (usually with Angular, but I assume it's unrelated) where some few select error messages repeat. One of which is that a dependency cannot be found (even though it's clearly listed and fetchable in our Nexus and locally) and another one is the one in the title, always talking about how a random folder inside the node_modules can't be deleted. This happens on the Jenkins machine as well as inside a docker build.
The one thing that always fixes these issues is pruning the docker cache and/or using npm cache clean --force.
Is there a better way to get rid of this kind of issues, or even prevent them?
